# Rails ActiveRecord insert a count field in record result

Tags: activerecord, model

Hi all thanks for the help :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :label, :description, :number

  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :posts, through: :user_posts

  after_initialize :count

  protected
  def count
    self.number = posts.count
  end
end
```

I whant the field :number to be the count of all posts of the user that (i think must be defined in function count I created in the model. Notice the :number field is not in the DB only in the model, but I want it to be available in the record returned by User.last for exemple.

I'm really new to ActiveRecord so maybe it's not this way I need to go, I'm open to any sugestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :label, :description
  attr_accessor :number

  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :posts, through: :user_posts

  after_initialize :count

  protected
  def count
    self.number = posts.count
  end

end
```

You don't need to specify `:number` in `attr_accessible` list as you are not taking the value of `number` from uer right?

For model only attributes (not persistent) the easiest way is, to use `attr_accessor`

Comment: Thanks for answer. The code works. But I think I'm doing wrong in what I want. I need to render my result in an array of json and in each json (each user) I need to insert a field (number) witch is the total of posts of the user. I thought doing it in the model was the good thing to do but I cannot access it in the ActiveRecord result. How can I do that ?

Comment: You should check out `rabl` gem. A railscast is also there.

Comment: Man this is exactly what I need.Just added a node in my rabl collection and it works ;p `node(:number) { |user| user.posts.count }`